# Gorilla Password Manager on Ubuntu 18.04 - problem with certain characters

Tags: 18.04, password

I have an old password set in **Gorilla Password Manager**. On Ubuntu 17.10 everything worked correctly.

After installing (not upgrade) Ubuntu 18.04, there is a problem with displaying certain characters. I use the **Czech characters** like <kbd>č</kbd>, <kbd>ž</kbd> and more. Words with these characters are unreadable.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Screenshot? "Unreadable" means wrong encoding, letters shown as replacement character �, letters shown as hexadecimal values, letters replaced with other characters? What version is your PasswordSafe database? What version is your Gorilla? What is your locale?

Comment: Further investigation showed that indeed, on 18.04 Password Gorilla does not like Romanian letters and clobbers them... But PasswordSafe (`sudo apt install passwordsafe`) does not suffer from this problem, and as far as I know uses the same file format.

Comment: PasswordSafe works. Thanks to @AlexP . Another solution is to use the latest stable **standalone** version of Gorilla Password Manager 1.5.37. Ubuntu 18.04 has the beta version 1.6.

Comment: Had the same problem with Japanese characters.  And once an opened psafe3 file is save, the characters are mangled permanently, even opening them in an older version.